# Android Notification Sound

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've used the newer NotificationCompat builder and I can't get the notification to make a sound. It will vibrate and flash the light. The android documentation says to set a style which I've done with:

```
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle());
```

But no sound?

The full code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)  
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)  
        .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")  
        .setContentText("This is a test notification");  


Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MenuScreen.class);  

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,   
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);  
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);
long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
builder.setVibrate(pattern);
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle());
// Add as notification  
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
manager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI) should also work

Answer (score 271, accepted):

What was missing from my previous code:

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(alarmSound);
```

Comment: It keeps playing and won't stop, how do I make it rings only once?
using builder.setOnlyOnce(true); doesn't help

Comment: its one time play

Comment: builder.setOnlyOnce(true) solved my problem in my case!

Answer (score 167):

Just put your sound file in the `Res\raw\siren.mp3` folder, then use this code:

For Custom Sound:

```
Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.siren);
```

For Default Sound:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

For Custom Vibrate:

```
long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
notification.vibrate = vibrate;
```

For Default Vibrate:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Answer (score 55):

Another way for the default sound

```
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 14):

On Oreo (Android 8) and above it should be done for custom sound in this way (notification channels):

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(
                         "android.resource://" + 
                         getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                         "/" + 
                         R.raw.push_sound_file);

AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .build();

// Creating Channel
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
                                                      "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME",
                                                      NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);

((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                                           .createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

Answer (score 13):

USE Can Codeding

```
 String en_alert, th_alert, en_title, th_title, id;
 int noti_all, noti_1, noti_2, noti_3, noti_4 = 0, Langage;

 class method
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReserveStatusActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


 intent = new Intent(String.valueOf(PushActivity.class));
 intent.putExtra("message", MESSAGE);
 TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
 stackBuilder.addParentStack(PushActivity.class);
 stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
 // PendingIntent pendingIntent =
 stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 //      android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
 //        bigStyle.bigText((CharSequence) context);



 notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle(th_title)
    .setContentText(th_alert)
    .setAutoCancel(true)

 // .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert)  ตัวเก่า
 //

 .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_title))

    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert))

    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setNumber(++numMessages)


    .build();

 notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

 notificationManager.notify(1000, notification);
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to use [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html)

```
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification myNotification;

    private final String myBlog = "http://niravranpara.blogspot.com/";
```

**Code for noficationmanager with alarm ringtone** you can also set ring tone RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(myBlog));
                  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Alarm", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    note.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm", "sound" + " (alarm)", pi);
                    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                    if(alarmSound == null){
                        alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                        if(alarmSound == null){
                            alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        }
                    }
                    note.sound = alarmSound;
                    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, note);
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't how you do it for the newer NotificationCompat.Builder.

Comment: Notification can be created with NotificationCompat.Builder.build() function and it's OK to take the return value of build() and modify its values before passing to NotificationManager.notify. It doesn't make much sense, but it's perfectly OK.

Answer (score 10):

Just put the below simple code :

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
        + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound_file);
```

For Default Sound:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can make a function:

```
public void playNotificationSound() 
{
    try
    {

        Uri alarmSound = `Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");`
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), alarmSound);
        r.play();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Call this function when you receive notification.

Here raw is the folder in res and the notification is the sound file in raw folder.

Answer (score 8):

In Android **OREO or later version** 
 [image]
**After Register the channel with the system;**
**you can't change the importance** 
or 
**other notification behaviors after this of same Channel**
(Before Uninstalling App)

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

channel.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI,audioAttributes);
```

**Priority also matters Most Here**
Set Notification **Priority to high** by using

**User-visible importance level     Importance (Android 8.0 and higher)**

**1)Urgent**
Makes a sound and appears as a heads-up notification-->**IMPORTANCE_HIGH**
**2)High**
Makes a sound -->**IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT**
**3)Medium**
No sound -->**IMPORTANCE_LOW**
**4)Low** No sound and does not appear in the status bar->**IMPORTANCE_MIN**

same works in same order
**Priority (Android 7.1 and lower)**

**1)PRIORITY_HIGH or PRIORITY_MAX**

**2)PRIORITY_DEFAULT**

**3)PRIORITY_LOW**

**4)PRIORITY_MIN**

Comment: "*you can't change the importance or other notification behaviors after this of same Channel*". Needed to uninstall app to make work, this action deleted channel's info from device as result.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use builder.[setSound](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);  

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent,   
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  

                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);  
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);
                long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
                builder.setVibrate(pattern);
                builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle());
                 Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                    if(alarmSound == null){
                        alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                        if(alarmSound == null){
                            alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        }
                    }

                // Add as notification  
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
             builder.setSound(alarmSound);
                manager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: You wrote RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE twice.

Answer (score 5):

1st put "yourmp3file".mp3 file in the raw folder(ie inside Res folder)

2nd in your code put..

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + v.getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.yourmp3file))//*see note
```

This is what i put inside my onClick(View v) as only "context().getPackageName()" wont work from there as it wont get any context

Answer (score 4):

```
private void showNotification() {

    // intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    //Notification sound
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // this is it, we'll build the notification!
    // in the addAction method, if you don't want any icon, just set the first param to 0
    Notification mNotification = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

        mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)

           .setContentTitle("Wings-Traccar!")
           .setContentText("You are punched-in for more than 10hrs!")
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wingslogo)
           .setContentIntent(pIntent)
           .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
           .addAction(R.drawable.favicon, "Goto App", pIntent)
           .build();

    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // If you want to hide the notification after it was selected, do the code below
    // myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);
}
```

call this function wherever you want. this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

by Notification.builder class instance  (builder) that is given below you can play default sound on notification:

```
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 0):

// set notification audio (Tested upto android 10)

```
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
//OR 
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    btn= findViewById(R.id.btn); 

   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notification();
        }
    });
  }   



private void notification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder= new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentTitle("Work Progress");
    builder.setContentText("Submit your today's work progress");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_email_black_24dp);
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, WorkStatus.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) 
    getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

It is complete notification with sound and vibrates

Answer (score 0):

Don't depends on builder or notification. Use custom code for vibrate.

```
public static void vibrate(Context context, int millis){
    try {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(millis, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            v.vibrate(millis);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several answers discuss the use of NotificationChannel.setSound() for Oreo (Android 8, api 26) and above, and that once a channel is created, it cannot be changed.

What I hadn't realised it that when AndroidStudio runs your app and performs an "Install" step, it appears ***not*** to uninstall the previous version and its NotificationChannel first.  Hence, changing something (e.g. the sound) and simply re-running will not work.  You need to *explicitly* uninstall the app first, before running it again.

Answer (score 0):

**This line for sound**

```
notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
```

**Example**

```
private fun createNotification()  {
    val downloadLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.drawable.download)
    val notificationManager = createNotificationChannel()
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "CHANNEL_ID")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.download)
        .setContentTitle("Download")
        .setContentText("Download Successfully")
        .setLargeIcon(downloadLogo)

    notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build())
}


private fun createNotificationChannel():NotificationManager {
    val notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = applicationContext.getString(R.string.channel_name)
        val descriptionText = applicationContext.getString(R.string.channel_description)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    return notificationManager
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp =MediaPlayer.create(Activity_Order_Visor_Atender.this, R.raw.ok);         
mp.start();
```

You create a packages between your resources with the name of raw and there you keep your sounds then you just call it.