# Android Notification custom Sound in galaxi s6

Tags: android, notifications

I try to play custom sound in my notification.

This is the code I use:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentText("")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_sound));
```

On Galaxy S3 it worked fine but on Galaxy s6 it's not working. The notification is generated but the sound is not played.

Can anyone tell me what the problem could be or give me a hint where to search?

Comment: How is the behavior? Does it give you an error? Please provide more information on how it fails.

Comment: there is no error, the notification works.  but there is no sound

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15855464/1306012
 Maybe you miss the permission to do so?