# I want set a notification that it should ring when i receive a notification

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

- I am creating a school application in which when i visit there for
  marketing i have to submit a report every time. If visit is
  Successful then there is no issue if visit is unsuccessful then i
  have to reschedule my meeting for next visit. When i set date and
  time for my next meeting it should remind me in early morning by
  sending a notification and it should alarm at that time so i can get
  reminder. here is my code for report Activity please help me

  ```
  private void sendNotificationDetailsTwo() {

      /* Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

      firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8); // At the hour you wanna fire
      firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // Particular minute
      firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // particular second
      Long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
      if (firingCal.compareTo(currentCal) < 0) {
          firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
      } else {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
              Intent newIntentTwo = new Intent(Report_Activity.this, MyReceiver.class);
              final int intent_id_two = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
              newIntentTwo.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
              bundle.putString("date", str_view_date);
              bundle.putString("time", str_view_time);
              bundle.putString("school_name", str_show_school_name);
              bundle.putInt("intent_id", intent_id_two);
              newIntentTwo.putExtras(bundle);
              AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)            Report_Activity.this.getSystemService(Report_Activity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);

              PendingIntent pendingIntent =    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Report_Activity.this, intent_id_two, newIntentTwo,    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
              alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
          }
      }*/

      /*alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);     alarmIntent = new Intent(context of current file, AlarmReceiver1.class); // AlarmReceiver1 = broadcast receiver

      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  Menu.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      alarmIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
      alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

      Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
      alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
      alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
      alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      if (now.after(alarmStartTime)) {
          Log.d("Hey","Added a day");
          alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
      }

      alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
      Log.d("Alarm","Alarms set for everyday 8 am.");*/

      Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar now       = Calendar.getInstance();
      firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
      firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,25);
      firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
      while(now.getTimeInMillis()>firingCal.getTimeInMillis()){
          firingCal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
      }
      Intent myInten = new Intent(Report_Activity.this,MyReceiver.class);
      final int intent_id_two = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
      myInten.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("date", str_view_date);
      bundle.putString("time", str_view_time);
      bundle.putString("school_name", str_show_school_name);
      bundle.putInt("intent_id", intent_id_two);
      myInten.putExtras(bundle);

      //final int intent_id_two = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
      PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Report_Activity.this,intent_id_two,myInten,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Report_Activity.this.getSystemService(Report_Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,firingCal.getTimeInMillis(),2000,myPendingIntent);


  }
  ```

  **MyAlarmService.java**

  ```
  public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

      private NotificationManager notificationManager;

      @Nullable
      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
        boolean alarm =(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent("Alarm"),PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)==null);


          if(alarm){
              Intent mintent =new Intent("Alarm");
              PendingIntent mpendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,mintent,0);
              Calendar mcalender = Calendar.getInstance();
              mcalender.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
              mcalender.add(Calendar.SECOND,3);
              AlarmManager malarmmanager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
              malarmmanager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,mcalender.getTimeInMillis(),6000,mpendingIntent);

          }
      }
  }
  ```

  **MyReceiver.java**

  ```
  public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      int MID = 0;
      int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      String date, time, school_name;
      PendingIntent pendingIntent;
      int intent_id;

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
          Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
          date = bundle.getString("date");
          time = bundle.getString("time");
          school_name = bundle.getString("school_name");
          intent_id = bundle.getInt("intent_id");
          NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
          notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
          //final int intent_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
          pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, intent_id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
          NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                  .setContentTitle("Notification From Dextro")
                  .setContentText("Meeting Schedule at " + school_name + " on " + date + " and time is " + time)
                  .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.dextro_customerlogo)
                  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                  .setAutoCancel(true)
                  .setSound(alarmSound)
                  .setTicker("Notification From Dextro")
                  .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                          .bigText("Meeting Schedule at " + school_name + " on " + date + " and time is " + time))
                  .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 100, 100, 100});
          notificationManager.notify(m, builder.build());
          MID++;
      }
  }
  ```

**1. In Simple way When i Reschedule my Work it should get notify me on
    next morning with alarm**

Comment: Checking this question may help you. [android-notification-sound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809399/android-notification-sound)

Comment: See when i set my Schedule with particular school name and date and time it should get submitted and on next morning it should remind me with with alarm please check my code

Comment: can any one tell me how i can create multiple notification on my status bar from above code i am getting same data multiple time

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 2000, 500, 2000, 500, 2000, 500});
    try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bells_bells_bells); //your sound file name from Raw folder
            .setSound(uri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can any one tell me how i can create multiple notification on my status bar from above code i am getting same data multiple time