# Add a sound while receiving text message in Java

Tags: android

I wanted to build a text message application in which If A user is sending a message B user should receive with a sound, how can I add that sound in my code?

Comment: Is your app the sender or receiver?  If the receiver, its easy to play a sound when you get a text, do a simple google search for sending a sound.  If you're the sender, there's no way to force the receiver's phone to play a sound when its received if they don't have their phone set up to do so.

Comment: Unless instead of a texting app you meant you're writing a chat app, and both people will have the app.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes, you got me here I am doing the same. Do you mean Android notification sound I have been searching from long all the time getting searches for notification sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For playing a sound when the user received the message, you can use [notification channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Because app should give control to a user they want to receive sound when incoming message received or not.

Notification channel gives more control to a user about a notification.

Like WhatsApp, it gives control to the user then want to receive the sound or mute

Comment: Notification channel  features is showing only in Android 8.0.  I am using Android 3.2.1 do we have any solution for that?

Comment: Notification builder has property for set sound, you can check device SDK version use that property

Comment: for more details for notification you can also check below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809399/android-notification-sound