# User setting preferred notification tone for the android app

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm new to android studio and I was wondering if there was any method wherein you could allow the user to set the notification tone. The notifications are generated using AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! **Put your songs files** in `Res\raw\`. Files Names should always be lowercase .

To allow the user set custom notification tone, you may need a `listview` or `recyclerview` where you list all songs you've put on `raw` folder. The user can listen to the tone and choose it.

Based on user choice you set the notification tone using this code in your alarm manager:

```
Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.siren); //if you have a file siren.mp3 in raw folder
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993700/12802591

To know what song the user has chosen, you need to implement **OnClick** method and retreive the song name and then pass it by **intent to the alarm manager**.

I recommend seeing tutorials on Recyclerview, ListView and other types of Views and Layouts. You should know available tools, how they works to solve any problem you have.

**-RecyclerView Tutorial :** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhhs4bwYyhc

**-ListView Tutorial :** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLFrwl1hFcw

(check the previous parts for better understanding)

Let me know if it solves your problem. Thanks!