# Notification sound is muted in system

Tags: java, android

On the system, notifications are muted for my app. How do I allow my app to play sound for notifications by default?[It's on all phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaHus.png)

Comment: Have you checked this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809399/android-notification-sound) and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the following code controls the notification sound

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```

Low importance means notifications are muted. High importance notifications notify the user.

But if the *Android System* disables the sound for an application, you might not be able to play sound for the notification.

Answer (score 0):

On pre Oreo devices, you can enable the notification sound by making the priority high

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) // Set priority to PRIORITY_HIGH to enable notification sound 
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

On Oreo and above devices, you must create a channel for  the notification

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Set importance to IMPORTANCE_HIGH to enable notification sound on Android 8.0 and above
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```